# Looking for the source of a teaching that HKBH always sides with the pursued, regardless of merit

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy

Shalom.

I heard a teaching a little while ago that HKBH always sides with the pursued, *regardless of merit*. I am quite sure this came from a reputable source.

Does anyone know the source for this teaching?

Many thanks.

Comment: Does this by any chanche sounds like it? https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaMiddot%2C_Conflict_and_Strife%2C_Part_I.61?ven=The_aleph_bet_book,_translated_by_Moshe_Mykoff._New_York:_Breslov_Research_Institute,_1986&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @Shmuel - thanks for the source, but no, this wasn’t it. My feeling is it was rishonim or before. Blessings all the same :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The source for this idea can be found in [Vayikra Rabba 27:5](https://library.alhatorah.org/?r1=Vayikra_Rabbah_27:5):

> וְהָאֱלֹהִים יְבַקֵּשׁ אֶת נִרְדָּף (קהלת ג׳:ט״ו), רַב הוּנָא בְּשֵׁם רַב יוֹסֵף אָמַר, לְעוֹלָם וְהָאֱלֹהִים יְבַקֵּשׁ אֶת נִרְדָּף, אַתָּה מוֹצֵא צַדִּיק רוֹדֵף צַדִּיק וְהָאֱלֹהִים יְבַקֵּשׁ אֶת נִרְדָּף, רָשָׁע רוֹדֵף צַדִּיק וְהָאֱלֹהִים יְבַקֵּשׁ אֶת נִרְדָּף, רָשָׁע רוֹדֵף רָשָׁע וְהָאֱלֹהִים יְבַקֵּשׁ אֶת נִרְדָּף, אֲפִלּוּ צַדִּיק רוֹדֵף רָשָׁע וְהָאֱלֹהִים יְבַקֵּשׁ אֶת נִרְדָּף, מִכָּל מָקוֹם וְהָאֱלֹהִים יְבַקֵּשׁ אֶת נִרְדָּף
>
> “G-d seeks the persecuted” (Ecclesiastes 3:15). Rav Huna said in the
> name of Rav Yosef: G-d always seeks the persecuted. If you find a
> righteous person persecuting a righteous person, “G-d seeks the
> persecuted”; a wicked person persecuting a righteous person, “G-d
> seeks the persecuted”; a wicked person persecuting a wicked person,
> “G-d seeks the persecuted”; even if a righteous person is persecuting
> a wicked person, in any case, “G-d seeks the persecuted.”