# Justice and the idea that God seeks the pursued

Tags: midrash, rodef

In a [recent question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/140904/looking-for-the-source-of-a-teaching-that-hkbh-always-sides-with-the-pursued-re), the OP sought a source for the idea that God "always sides with the pursued, regardless of merit" and the accepted answer came from Leviticus Rabbah 27:5:

> וְהָאֱלֹהִים יְבַקֵּשׁ אֶת נִרְדָּף (קהלת ג, טו), רַב הוּנָא בְּשֵׁם
> רַב יוֹסֵף אָמַר, לְעוֹלָם וְהָאֱלֹהִים יְבַקֵּשׁ אֶת נִרְדָּף, אַתָּה
> מוֹצֵא צַדִּיק רוֹדֵף צַדִּיק וְהָאֱלֹהִים יְבַקֵּשׁ אֶת נִרְדָּף,
> רָשָׁע רוֹדֵף צַדִּיק וְהָאֱלֹהִים יְבַקֵּשׁ אֶת נִרְדָּף, רָשָׁע
> רוֹדֵף רָשָׁע וְהָאֱלֹהִים יְבַקֵּשׁ אֶת נִרְדָּף, אֲפִלּוּ צַדִּיק
> רוֹדֵף רָשָׁע וְהָאֱלֹהִים יְבַקֵּשׁ אֶת נִרְדָּף, מִכָּל מָקוֹם
> וְהָאֱלֹהִים יְבַקֵּשׁ אֶת נִרְדָּף
>
> And God seeketh that which is pursued (Eccl. 3:15). R. Huna in the
> name of R. Joseph explained: Always 'God seeketh that which is
> pursued'. You find a case where a righteous man pursues a righteous
> man, 'And God seeketh that which is pursued'; where a wicked man
> pursues a righteous man, 'And God seeketh that which is pursued';
> where a wicked man pursues a wicked man, 'And God seeketh that which
> is pursued'; even where a righteous man pursues a wicked man, 'And God
> seeketh that which is pursued.'

What does a *rodef* mean in this context (someone with an actual *din rodef*, a legally defined pursuer out to commit murder?)? And what does it mean that God is *yebhaqesh* (seeks/desires) them?

At face value, the idea that the righteous ought not prosecute the wicked doesn't really conform to our sense of justice. Indeed, even the peshat of the originating pasuq seems to imply the opposite, i.e. that the wicked are held to account for their iniquity. Rashi Qoheleth 3:15:

> והאלהים יבקש את נרדף - ליפרע מן הרודף לפיכך מה יתרונו של עושה הרעה
> באשר הוא עמל הרי סופו להשתלם
>
> and God seeks the pursued: to punish the pursuer. Therefore, what is
> the profit of one who does evil in what he toils? He is destined to be
> called to account.

What idea is the Midrash trying to communicate here?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of we are Hashem's children, even the wicked. A father has Rachmanut on his children. If the good ones persecute the wicked one, the father will be upset by this. Especially if the persecution is over the top or not coming from a good place. That's my initial thought and I wondered if that resonates with you, if so I might try and source it

Comment: The medrash seems to be saying that there is an intrinsic *maalah* in being a *nirdaf*, e.g. from the analogy to doves which are *kosher* for the *mizbeach* since they are a *nirdaf*. This seems to imply that there is a purifying factor in being a *nirdaf*. Maybe the purifying factor is that a *nirdaf* always needs to see past the *ha'nireh lichorah* (the immediately obvious) in order to survive, and therefore is closer to Hashem.

Comment: Cf ילקוט שמעוני תהלים ל"ב:י'
רבי אליעזר ורבי תנחום בשם רבי ירמיה אפילו רשע ובוטח בה' חסד יסובבנו.

Comment: The righteous can "prosecute" the wicked, but not "persecute" them.

Comment: @RabbiKaii "Especially if the persecution is over the top or not coming from a good place." I think motive is likely an important aspect of understanding this  "if so I might try and source it" Go for it bro :)

Comment: @TheGRAPKE good observations! would be interesting to see any commentary that takes that angle.

Comment: @Nahum thanks I'll check it out

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi I think you and RabbiKaii are both touching on a key to unlocking this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of this midrash is that a righteous person pursuing a wicked person is punished when the righteous person's own pursuit is wicked or involves some wickedness, not when the pursuit is completely righteous.

The meaning of יְבַקֵּשׁ is "seek," and (as Rashi says, quoted in your question) it refers to meting out punishment, as in דֹרֵשׁ דָּמִים ([Psalms 9:13](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Tehillim/9/13#e0n6)). בקש is a synonym of דרש; here as there the grammatical object of the verb is the victim (like the word "avenge" in English), and the object of the punishment is only implied. The [same midrash](https://library.alhatorah.org/?r1=Vayikra_Rabbah_27:5) continues with a clear restatement of this idea (as learned from other scriptural sources) in different but synonymous terms (תּוֹבֵעַ דָּמָן שֶׁל נִרְדָּפִין מִן הָרוֹדְפִין).

The technical case of רודף (i.e. attempted murder or rape) is not the general meaning of the term נִרְדָּף here (as I understand it), but it is a particular instance of it and it offers a perfect illustration: you are allowed to kill the attempted murderer, but if you were able to stop him in any way other than killing and you choose to kill, then you are guilty of murder ([Sanhedrin 74a](https://shas.alhatorah.org/Full/Sanhedrin/74a.2#e0n6); the same is true in monetary cases, see [Bava Kamma 28a](https://shas.alhatorah.org/Full/Bava_Kamma/28a.4#e0n6)). The punishment of the pursuer could accordingly be due to some unlawful aspect in his pursuit.

Alternatively, the midrash could even be referring to lawfully pursuing someone for a personal reason (this seems to be the meaning of the [Etz Yosef](https://www.sefaria.org/Etz_Yosef_on_Vayikra_Rabbah.27.5.2?lang=bi)'s comment here<sup>1</sup>), in which case this would apply even to a pursuer who is fully within his rights, for not going beyond the letter of the law (as in [Bava Metzia 30b](https://shas.alhatorah.org/Full/Bava_Metzia/30b.14#e0n6)).

In either case, it is the very fact of being a pursuer that tips the scales towards the pursued. This is precisely the peshat of the verse which says that God seeks the נִרְדָּף, as such, and fits in precisely with the wording you quoted from Rashi: the person doing evil (עושה הרעה), not necessarily the more evil person, is punished.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>לא שרודפו על רשעתו דא"כ מצוה קעביד. אלא מיירי שרודפו להנאתו. The word להנאתו means not for fun (we're talking about a צדיק), but for something that rightfully belongs to him as an individual, as opposed to לשם שמים.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. +1! (I think with some minor editing, I can accept this answer)... "The meaning of יְבַקֵּשׁ is "seek," and (as Rashi says, quoted in your question) it refers to meting out punishment," If this is the intended meaning within this midrash then what is R. Yehuda saying/adding that is different than R. Huna (see the continuation inside)?

Comment: “The classic case of רודף (i.e. attempted murder or rape) is not the general meaning of the term נִרְדָּף here (as I understand it), but it is an instance of it and it offers a perfect illustration” I find this confusing. Are you saying that it is being used in the sense of having a din rodef or not? What is the evidence for one direction or another?

Comment: Thanks for bringing down the עץ יוסף! This is similar to what you write at the beginning "My understanding of this midrash is that a righteous person pursuing a wicked person is punished when the righteous person's own pursuit is wicked or involves some wickedness, not when the pursuit is completely righteous."

Comment: @Deuteronomy 1. My understanding: there is no difference in the concept between Rav Huna and Rabbi Yehuda Berabbi Simon, only in how they learn it. Rav Huna learns this from the verse in Ecclesiastes (the verse says "pursued"). RYBRS learns this from the fact that God favors the persecuted over the persecutor consistently (not incidentally, where it could be that one specific victim was righteous). Rabbi Eliezer Berabbi Yosi ben Zimra then learns the same concept from the animals chosen for sacrifices (not because the prey is more righteous than the predator but because it is prey).

Comment: 2. Rodef literally means pursuer, but as a technical term it has a more limited meaning, which excludes e.g. hurting someone non-lethally. I don't think the limited meaning is the correct interpretation here, since we shouldn't assume a word that has a non-technical meaning is being used in the technical sense. I think the intended meaning of pursuing is something like this: attempting to do something undesirable by force. That would include the technical rodef but would not be limited to it. The din rodef would then derive from this concept (but it also shows up for property damage as in BK).

Comment: 3. Actually I took the Etz Yosef as being different from my first answer (I wrote it second to stress the chiddush). At first I said that logically this shouldn't apply if you're acting fully within your rights. If it's your right, why should you be punished? So I said it must be you're overstepping your rights in some way. Then I brought the Etz Yosef who (as I understand him) says no, even if you're pursuing him for a personal reason (להנאתו, not for fun, but for something that rightfully belongs to him as an individual, as opposed to לשם שמים), you're punished for the very act of pursuing.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to clarify... I'm going to accept your answer :) Maybe edit in some of these comments לטובת הציבור in case the comments get deleted at some point.